# Recording vugen script for application which launches through a macro

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I want to create a vugen script for launching an application which launches once the macro is run in excel.
How should I incorporate this step in loadrunner of launching through macro ? 
Application is using http/html protocol.

Comment: Do you mean you want to record an application started by an Excel macro?

Answer (score 0):

Use Proxy recorder.  Set your global proxy to the LoadRunner HTTP recording proxy.  They do not have to be on the same host as long as you have no firewall complications which would prevent communication to another host.